# passing Double Vector or Array as neuroph.setInput() paramater

Tags: java, vector, parameter-passing, neural-network, overloading

I am working on Neuroph ANN framework. There is this point when after training the neural network, it is tested for new inputs using the following method (the library is open source, so i was able to refer to the actual implementation inside the library that i imported[1](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/54896551/#l-211)):

```
/**
 * Sets network input. Input is an array of double values.
 *
 * @param inputVector network input as double array
 */
public void setInput(double... inputVector) throws VectorSizeMismatchException {
    if (inputVector.length != inputNeurons.size()) {
        throw new VectorSizeMismatchException("Input vector size does not match network input dimension!");
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (Neuron neuron : this.inputNeurons) {
        neuron.setInput(inputVector[i]); // set input to the coresponding neuron
        i++;
    }

}
```

Sadly, i am having so much difficulty passing the paremeters. At first, i would successfully pass each Double value separated by comma. But then my input size increased to 400. I have tried to pass inputs as Double Vector as well as Double Array (blind shot), but i am getting errors that the method cannot be resolved with such parameter.

Here is the code snippet where i am doing so:

```
public String predict(String features)
{
    // load the saved network
    NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork = NeuralNetwork.createFromFile(nnet_path);
    // set network input

    String[] feature_pieces = features.split(" ");

    System.out.println("\nINPUT FEATURES: " + Arrays.toString(feature_pieces));

    Double[] feature_pieces_double = new Double[feature_pieces.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < feature_pieces.length; i++) {
        feature_pieces_double[i] = Double.parseDouble(feature_pieces[i]);

    }

    Vector<Double> features_vector = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(feature_pieces_double));

    //neuralNetwork.setInput(feature_pieces_double); //TODO

    neuralNetwork.setInput(features_vector); //TODO
.
.
.
```

Please help me what am i doing wrong.

For reference, [here is the javadoc](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/neuroph/core/NeuralNetwork.html#setInput-double...-) section which mentions this method. (The javadoc strangely does not say anything about the overloaded method that takes Array as input)

P.s. someone with sufficient reputation, please add more useful tags

Comment: I'm guessing that the source you reference is not the source of the library you are using. You could inspect the class in your IDE to see if it actually declares that method (or alternatively via commandline, run `javap` on the `.class` file of NeuralNetwork).

Comment: @Kenney you are right, upon checking the actual library import, there is only one method, that takes vector type.
However, the problem remains, i am unable to do it even with vectors.

Let me edit the question to remove the second method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a Vector:

```
double[] feature_pieces_double = new double[feature_pieces.length];

for (int i = 0; i < feature_pieces.length; i++) {
    feature_pieces_double[i] = Double.parseDouble(feature_pieces[i]);
}

neuralNetwork.setInput(feature_pieces_double);
```

But make sure to use `double` and not `Double`.

The `args` in the following method is an array:

```
public void method(double... args)
```

and so this is equivalent to

```
public void method(double[] args)
```

(except that with `...` you have the added bonus of being able to directly specify the arguments in the method call separated by commas: `method(1.0, 2.0)`).

Comment: oh my God! it was the primitive type double! silly me. Thank you a ton sir!